# How to implement a parser based on the following grammar?

Tags: java, parsing

How to implement a parser based on the following grammar:

```
exp ::= exp + term|exp - term|term
term ::= (exp)|integer literal
```

I understand how to implement a parser for:

```
exp ::= term + exp|term - exp|term
```

But I am confused how to implement it for:

```
exp ::= exp + term|exp - term|term
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
private static Exp parseExp(Tokenizer t) throws ParseException {
    // add code in this method for your solution
    //<exp> ::= <exp> + <term>|<exp> - <term>|<term>
    Exp term = parseTerm(t);
    if (!t.done()){
        if (t.current().isTheSymbol('+')){
            t.next();
            Exp exp = parseExp(t);
            return new BinExp(exp,'+',term);
        }
        else if (t.current().isTheSymbol('-')){
            t.next();
            Exp exp = parseExp(t);
            return new BinExp(exp,'-',term);
        }
        else return term;
    }
    else return term;
}
```

For example with 2-1+3, it parses to ((3+1)-2), but I expect ((2-1)+3)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you rewrite your rule as:

```
exp ::= term (('+'|'-') term)*

private static Exp parseExp(Tokenizer t) throws ParseException {
    // add code in this method for your solution
    //<exp> ::= <exp> + <term>|<exp> - <term>|<term>
    Exp exp = parseTerm(t);
    while (!t.done()) {
        char op;
        if (t.current().isTheSymbol('+')) {
            op = '+';
        }
        else if (t.current().isTheSymbol('-')){
            op = '-';
        }
        else {
           break;
        }
        t.next();
        Exp exp2 = parseTerm(t);
        exp = new BinExp(exp,op,exp2);
    }
    return exp;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the rule cannot be revised.

Comment: @Jenny it isn't. It's the same rule.